# Как отобразить сообщение ошибки, записанное в комментариях C++

Tags: c++, type-error

Я создал заголовочный файл в C++, в котором описал через #define коды ошибок

*myError.h*

```
//
// MessageId: ERROR_LOGIN
//
// MessageText:
//
// Wrong login
#define  ERROR_NAME    100L

//
// MessageId: ERROR_PASSWORD
//
// MessageText:
//
// Wrong password
#define  ERROR_PASSWORD 101L
```

Как написать функцию string getDescription(int errorNumber), которая будет возвращать мне текстовое сообщение ошибки по её номеру.

Например:

```
cout <<  getDescription(ERROR_NAME);
cout <<  getDescription(ERROR_PASSWORD);
```

Должна вернуть

```
"Wrong login"
"Wrong password"
```

Answer (score 2):

Один из возможных вариантов: 
создайте ассоциативный контейнер *map*, где ключ - это код ошибки, а std::string - это описание Вашей ошибки. Следовательно функция *getDescription* будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
// map - имя переменной ассоциативного контейнера
std::string getDescription(int code)
{
    if(map.find(code) != map.end()) 
       return map[code];
    return std::string::npos;  // строки нет, или же ""
}
```